# Adding two images into one R mixing their colors

Tags: r, image, colors, overlay

Hi All I have a matrix of size 1000 width and 500 height. I know how to use the tiff and image function in R to make an image from the matrix. I have made 2 images where imageA has colorcode colorRamPalette(c("white","red","black")) and imageB has colorcode colorRamPalette(c("white","blue","black")). I am trying to combine the 2 images to create one image where the colors are also mixed appropriately. I did the following:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
RED<-raster("imageA.tiff");
BLUE<-raster("imageB.tiff");
RB <- overlay(RED, BLUE,fun=sum)
tiff("imageAB.tiff",width=1000,height=500,units="px");
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("black","red","blue","white"))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(RB, xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=my_palette, useRaster=TRUE);
dev.off()
```

I assumed the overlay function will mix the colors along with overlaying one image on top of another but i am lacking how to show the coloring scheme the outputs when red image is overlayed on blue. I am grateful for your help.

Example images:

```
r <- 1000
c <- 500
m0 <- matrix(0, r, c)
m1 <- apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1)) 

tiff("m1.tiff",width=1000,height=500,units="px");
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","white"));
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(m1,xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=my_palette(256),useRaster=TRUE);
dev.off()

m2 <- apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))
tiff("m2.tiff",width=1000,height=500,units="px");
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red","white"));
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(m2,xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=my_palette(256),useRaster=TRUE);
dev.off()
```

After merging the two images the output image should be the color of adding the two images blue+red=magentaish (appropriately).
I used the raster function as shown here and didn't use any other variables here.

After Robert's reply:
I edited my code and this works as expected:

```
r <- 1000
c <- 500
m0 <- matrix(0, r, c)
m1 <- apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1)) 

tiff("m1and2.tiff",width=1000,height=500,units="px");
my_palette1 <- colorRampPalette(c("white","red"));   
m2 <- apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))
my_palette2 <- colorRampPalette(c("white","blue"))(256);
my_palette2<-paste(my_palette2, sprintf("%x", ceiling(255*0.5)), sep="");#alpha=0.5

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(m1, xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=(my_palette1(256)),useRaster=TRUE);
image(m2, xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", bty="n", col=my_palette2,add=TRUE,useRaster=TRUE);
dev.off()
```

I also found an add=TRUE parameter for image function.

Comment: please provide some minimal example data like `r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5, vals=1:25)` etc. it would also be useful to know if you can define "appropriately" with a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps. The idea is to plot twice, the second time with 50% transparency. `image` has no `add=TRUE` but you can use `graphics::rasterImage` directly with partially transparent colors.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- raster(matrix(0, 5, 5))
r1[c(1,3,5), ] <- 1
r2[, c(1,3,5)] <- 1

pal1 <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","white"));
pal2 <- colorRampPalette(c("red","white"));

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(r1, col=pal1(2), legend=FALSE, legend.mar=0, legend.width=0)
plot(r2, col=pal2(2), alpha=.5, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert based on your answer I changed my above code and it works.